# Self-hosting .NET Remoting and OWIN on the same port?

Tags: owin, remoting

I have a legacy application server built using .NET remoting over TCP in a Windows service. I want to introduce some OWIN dependent frameworks, like WebAPI and SignalR without requiring a new port.

My attempts to register both .NET remoting and OWIN on the same port have thus far failed.

If I start OWIN first, the remoting configuration fails with a `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException` "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions".

If I start remoting first, then OWIN startup fails with a `System.Net.HttpListenerException` "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

This doesn't surprise me. But the question remains, is there a way to make this configuration work?

Comment: Probably not a good idea. You can only have one "thing" listening on a socket, regardless of whether it's in the same process or not. You would have to create your own TCP Listener and then inspect and forward requests to Owin and Remoting. Not worth the headache, just use separate ports.

Comment: Or instead of going as low-level as a TCP listener, might it be possible with a piece of OWIN middleware?

Comment: Owin opens an Http listener, which will only work for Remoting if your channel is over Http.